# How to get indexpath in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
    {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Action"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tbl indexPathForSelectedRow];
        SecondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.getString = [getArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

i wanna to access the selected row `index`,but show `null` for every selected row. please help me?

Comment: Pls check self.tbl != nil

Comment: You haven't made connection of tbl variable to tableview into storyboard.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Swift 3.0 / iOS 10

`tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` was introduced in iOS 9

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! ParkDetailTableVC
        detailVC.park = self.parksArray[selectedRow]
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note the parallel property on collection views, `indexPathsForSelectedItems`, which might be used like so: 

```if let selectedIndexPathRow = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first?.row {
    doStuff(with: myDataSourceArr[selectedIndexPathRow]
}
```

Answer (score 66):

Two cases:

1. `Segue` connected from the `viewController`

   Call `segue` from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, pass `indexPath` as `sender`

   ```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Action" sender:indexPath];
   }
   ```

   Then you can get indexPath as sender in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method

   ```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
   {
       if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Action"])
       {
           NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
           SecondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
           destViewController.getString = [getArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       }
   }
   ```
2. segue connected from the cell

   No need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.You can directly get `sender` as `UITableviewCell` in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

   ```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
   {
       if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Action"])
       {
           NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
           SecondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
           destViewController.getString = [getArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @PintuRajput, you should not do it this way if you've connected the segue directly from the cell. In that case, the sender argument will be the cell, and you can use the tableView method indexPathForCell: to get the indexPath from the sender. If your segue is from the cell, you shouldn't implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath, or call performSegue.

Comment: Thats true, in my case the segue from ViewController itself.

Comment: sender is the object that caused the change you should not use it to pass a param like an index path, it needs to be a UIView or UIViewController, and if its set to nil then it gets set to the current view controller before it gets passed up to a container controller like a split controller because it needs it to be valid and the correct kind of object.

Answer (score 4):

Like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender {
    FTGDetailVC *detailVC = (id)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    FTGNote *note = self.notes[indexPath.row];
    [detailVC updateWithNote:note];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i don't understand what you want to do.
it's possible get the `indexPath.row` through this method of `UITAbleViewDelegate` that it's called when you tap the cell of your tableView:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{     
    self.myVariable = indexPath.row
}
```

and then you can access to this value in the `prepareForSegue` in this way:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    //do something with self.myVariable
}
```

I hope i helped you.

Comment: That's not necessarily true if tapping that cell raises your Segue. Would not work.