# How to prepareForSegue in a UICollectionView depending on the contents of cell?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with custom cells which display certain elements of a dictionary.

This is the dictionary;

```
-(instancetype)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    EventsLibrary *eventsLibrary = [[EventsLibrary alloc]init];
    NSArray *library = eventsLibrary.library;

    NSDictionary *eventsDictionary = library[index];

    _eventTitle = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kTitle];
    _eventLocation = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kLocation];
    _eventPrice = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kPrice];
    _eventDate = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kDate];
    _eventTime = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kTime];
    _eventDescription = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kDescription];
    _eventIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:[eventsDictionary objectForKey:kIcon]];
    _eventIconLarge = [UIImage imageNamed:[eventsDictionary objectForKey:kLargeIcon]];

    _eventType = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kType];
}
return self;
}
```

The kVariables all have strings associated with them in an array labeled library.

I have been able to have the UICollectionView display what I needed on a specific view controller (eventTitle, eventLocation, eventPrice, eventIcon). I'm struggling now, in terms of having a segue which responds dependant on the cell selected. I have been successful in doing this for a UIImageView NSArray - yet I'm unfamiliar on how to work around this problem with a UICollectionView and a UICollectionViewCell.

I would like to perform a segue in order to further display (dependant on which cell was selected), some values from the dictionary which haven't yet been used (i.e. description).

I'm confused as to whether the ideal method would be written in the performSegue method or in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath??

Below is some additional code and screen shots for more information;

**Story board of two view controllers with the segue identifier**

[image: Storyboard of two viewcontrollers]

**Code for the initial viewcontroller with the UICollectionView on how the arrays are filled and the UICollectionView labels/images are associated**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.eventTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
self.eventLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
self.eventIconArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.eventPriceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
self.eventTypeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
self.eventDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];

for (NSUInteger index = 0; (index < 8) ; index++){

    EventsList *eventList = [[EventsList alloc] initWithIndex:index];

    NSString *individualEventTitle = eventList.eventTitle;
    NSString *individualEventLocation = eventList.eventLocation;
    NSString *individualEventIcon = eventList.eventIcon;
    NSString *individualEventPrice = eventList.eventPrice;
    NSString *individualEventType = eventList.eventType;
    NSArray *eventDate = eventList.eventDate;


    [self.eventTitleArray addObject:individualEventTitle];
    [self.eventLocationArray addObject:individualEventLocation];
    [self.eventIconArray addObject:individualEventIcon];
    [self.eventPriceArray addObject:individualEventPrice];
    [self.eventTypeArray addObject:individualEventType];
    [self.eventDateArray addObjectsFromArray:eventDate];

    }
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
EventsCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"eventsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.eventImage.image = [self.eventIconArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventTitle.text = [self.eventTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventLocation.text = [self.eventLocationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventPrice.text = [self.eventPriceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventType.text = [self.eventTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

**I am able to currently click on the cells in the simulator, yet the second view controller has no content - as presumed due to there being no method in the segue**

Hence I would appreciate some knowledge on how I would work around this with a UICollectionView?

**prepareForSegue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
EventView *collectionView = [[EventView alloc]init];
if([segue.identifier isEqual: @"showEventDetail"]){
    if([self.yourEvents indexPathForCell:sender]){
        NSIndexPath *index = [self.yourEvents indexPathForCell:sender];
        collectionView.eventTitle.text = @"Hello";
        collectionView.eventDescription.text = @"This Event";
    }
}
}
```

The secondary viewController wont even update its properties `collectionView.eventTitle.text` to the hard string of `@"Hello"`. Although when I `NSLog` the `NSIndexPath *index` - I get different values dependant on which cell I select. So I presume that the secondary VC is loading different instances dependant on the cell selected? Yet I'm more confused as to why the actual properties wont even change when assigned a hard string value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your actual question is *whether the ideal method would be written in the performSegue method or in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath*.

If this is the case, both can work.

You can try first `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and pass the model object (in your case that could be `Event`) to the detail view controller. That could look like this:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Get the Event model representing the currently selected cell
    Event *selectedEvent = self.events[indexPath.row];

    // Create a new detail view controller with the selected event and push it
    EventDetailViewController *eventDetailViewController = [[EventDetailViewController alloc] initWithEvent: selectedEvent];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

If you want to use segues, your goal is again to get the selected `indexPath`. You can achieve that by using `UICollectionView`'s `indexPathForCell` method as described in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26278949/289501).

Note that it might simplify your code a lot if you use a dedicated model class (the `Event` one I mentioned earlier) and then have an array of events as your datasource.

Comment: Thank you for your response phi,

However, I'm rather confused with regards to where you've said to initialise the eventDetailViewController with initWithEvent? Wouldn't this require me to have a method of some sort in the object "Event"?

I've been trying to use the performSegue method **I've updated the original question with the method added**. Through NSLog I have been able to determine the index path varies dependant on the cell I select which is good. However, I'm unable to alter the contents of the secondary slide?

Comment: Before trying to help you more, I would suggest you to read [this article](http://matteomanferdini.com/the-correct-way-to-display-lists-in-ios-and-what-many-developers-do-wrong/) because it covers the basics of what you're trying to do.

Comment: My apologies! I thought I had edited my own question and by accident edited your answer. I've looked into that article however, as I'm still rather new to objective-c please excuse my lack of knowledge but how applicable is the context from UITableView to UICollectionView? Also the article itself refers to Swift, which I'm not too familiar with. 

I have a theory, with regards to the UILabels in the secondary viewcontroller, do I have to initialise them in viewDidLoad for them to have their properties assigned from the previous view controller prepareForSegue method?

Comment: Thanks for all the help phi. I've been able to tinker around with the code and got it working :)

Comment: UITableView and UICollectionView are very similar. Please try to ignore Swift and focus on understanding the concept of passing data between the "master" and the "detail" view controller. The "Quote" class in the article should be the "Event" class in your example. Then, it will be easier to understand how to populate your view controllers and separate the view from the model.