# Passing data from table view cell to new view controller error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to pass data from my tableViewCell, however, keep getting an error on my 
`let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell`

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value.

How would I make my cell an optional? I'm trying to pass the data from an array.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? UsersProfileViewController{


        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let selectedRow = partnerTable.indexPath(for: cell)?.row

        if let name = usersArray[selectedRow!].firstLastName{
            destination.name = name

        }  
    }




   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toUser", sender: nil)

}
}
```

Comment: What are you passing when you call the segue?

Comment: How are you triggering the segue?  Set a breakpoint and check what `sender` is.

Comment: this is because you are passing nil in sender `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toUser", sender: nil)`

Comment: use indexPath.row as sender i have given answer below

Comment: Firstly you'll need to get a right index using `indexPathForSelectedRow`. And it's should be like this: `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toUser", sender: self)`

Comment: Here exactly same one          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278730/how-to-get-indexpath-in-prepareforsegue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should trigger this way

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toUser", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

and in prepare for segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    let selectedRow = sender as? Int
    if let name = usersArray[selectedRow!].firstLastName{
        destination.name = name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use segue using storyboard:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? UsersProfileViewController else {return}
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        destinationVC.name = usersArray[selectedRow].firstLastName
    }
}
```

You can also segue to the destination ViewController programatically and pass the required value to that Controller.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:  IndexPath) {
  let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "StoryboardName", bundle:     nil)
  let destinationVC = sb.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: "StoryboardId for viewcontroller set in storyboard") as?                                         UsersProfileViewController
   guard let name = usersArray[selectedRow!].firstLastName { else return }
   destinationVC.name = name
   self.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**Steps:**

1. Get an instance of the storyboard.
2. Instantiate the required viewcontroller with the help of storyboard Id which is assigned in the storyboard.
3. Pass the data required to destination VC.
4. Present the destination View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got one thing from you post, you want to get current selected tableview data and want to pass it to next view controller, you can do this in a simple way. Check tableview cell selected delegate method

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

From this delegate method you can save selected row index and in prepare segue method call this function in this way , selectedRow value you can set in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

```
usersArray[selectedRow!].firstLastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps To Do:

1. First of all create the property selectedIndex in View controller.
2. set the selectedIndex property value with indexPath from didSelectRowAtIndexPath table view's delegate methods.
3. In Prepare for Segue method you can find the data value from your datasource object as you have selected index.

4.Pass the value from datasource for selected index and make selectedIndex property to nil.