# Get indexPath for segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to get indexPath for existing cell for certain segue actions.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "EditItem" {
       let controller = segue.destination as! TimerSelectViewController
       controller.delegate = self
       if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
       controller.itemToEdit = timers[indexPath.row]
           }
       }
    }
```

I call segue in didSelectRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditItem", sender: nil)

}
```

But everytime I click on cell I get nil and my app crash. I don't understand why

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)
```

returns each time nil.

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/admin/Projects/Timer/Timer/TimersTableViewController.swift, line 185

Comment: I added more context to the question post.

Comment: That’s really not much of an adding... you need to add the didSelectRawAtIndexPath implementation to let us understand how do you call the perform segue

Comment: I added my segue implementation at didSelectRawAt.

Comment: Than my answer is your problem. You pass nil as sender, than you want to use it as a cell. If you want the cell to be passed you need to call the cellForIndexPath method of the tableView and pass the cell you get as sender in the perform segue.

Comment: Thank you! You answered my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you didn’t pass anything as sender in the performSegue method or the thing you passed is not an instance of UITableViewCell or it’s subclass.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I didn't passed anything as sender in the performSegue method.

Answer (score 0):

if the requirement is to get the indexpath of a selected cell then this might be a duplicate of [How to get indexpath in prepareForSegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278730/how-to-get-indexpath-in-prepareforsegue).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question:

I added to didSelectRowAt cell and put it in sender for performSegue:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditItem", sender: cell)

}
```